# Strange JSON-String distortion in Tomcat

Tags: java, json, tomcat, javafx

Please explain to me, what is the cause of distortion of JSON-String sent from JavaFX application to Tomcat server. Part of symbols is replaced by strange square symbols:

[image: screenshot-1 of JSON-String printed to console]

Conversation to JSON pass correctly – I checked it by printing JSON-String to console in JavaFX app after serializing. But after transfer to Tomcat-server by DoPost method JSON-String is distorted. And I tried to transfer XML too – it distorts by the same way.

After small investigation, I got some result: String sent by DoPost stays correct if it's length is 7782 symbols or less. Plus one symbol – and squares appears:

[image: screenshot-2 of JSON-Strings printed to console]

Both the JavaFX app and Tomcat server starts on local machine under Intellij IDEA, so it's not a network problem.

Comment: mmm.... can I provide link to all code on github? 

JavaFX app:
https://github.com/swen922/TimeCountFXProbe2/tree/master/src

Tomcat:
https://github.com/swen922/TimeCountServer

Comment: Exactly: 
on JavaFX this object:
https://github.com/swen922/TimeCountFXProbe2/blob/master/src/com/horovod/timecountfxprobe/serialize/BaseToServerWrapper.java

is sent to Tomcat by this thread:
https://github.com/swen922/TimeCountFXProbe2/blob/master/src/com/horovod/timecountfxprobe/threads/ThreadSendBaseToServer.java

and Tomcat receive string in this Servlet:
https://github.com/swen922/TimeCountServer/blob/master/src/app/ReceiveBaseFromClient.java

Comment: Possibly an encoding issue.

Comment: Nop ))  But I got exact cause on russian Stackoverflow, see my answer (will post soon)

Answer (score 0):

Very thanks to user **Nick** on ru.stackoverflow.com:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/216863/nick

He gave exact cause – length of inputStream. GZIP gives not correct value of inputStream length to Servlet. 
And when I replaced this code:
`public String getInputString(HttpServletRequest req) {
        String receivedString = "";

```
    int len = req.getContentLength();
    byte[] input = new byte[len];

    try {
        ServletInputStream sin = req.getInputStream();
        int c = 0;
        int count = 0;
        while ((c = sin.read(input, count, (input.length - count))) > 0) {
            count += 1;
        }
        sin.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }

    receivedString = new String(input);

    return receivedString;
}`[PasteBin-1][1]
```

by this:
`public String getInputString(HttpServletRequest req) {
        String receivedString = "";

```
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(req.getInputStream()))) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");

        while (reader.ready()) {
            sb.append(reader.readLine());
        }

        if (sb.length() > 0) {
            receivedString = sb.toString();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }

    return receivedString;
}`[PasteBin-2][2]
```

everything started to work correctly.

This is same question thread on russian:
[answer on ru.stackoverflow.com](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/958236/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5-json-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-tomcat/959019#959019)